# Does node.js use thread per socket connection?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, threadpool

I understand how Node.js works with single thread. Mostly it is using asynchronous methods/modules in order to keep the main runtime thread free as much as possible.

However, some of the asynchronous modules internally are using threads to do their job. Example for this is reading file or other high intensive CPU task. This is done in background and it  is abstracted for the Node developer.

My question is , how internally Socket.IO works, does it use threads like the above examples ? Does it use separate thread per connection ? If so , does it mean that we will have 1000 threads, if we have 1000 connected clients ?

Comment: no, sockets doesn't use threads. everything on top of tcp (http, websockets, etc.) doesn't either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node does not use the thread pool (or separate threads) for sockets, instead it uses whatever platform-specific mechanism for polling sockets for data (e.g. epoll on Linux, kqueue on OS X (IIRC), I/O completion ports on Windows, etc.) on the main thread.

Answer (score -2):

Socket.io works on the event loop like most node applications. No tricky thread business AFAIK. You can check out the source yourself here: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io

Comment: Using the event loop doesn't guarantee that it does't use threads.  Every callback is using the event loop, including the asynchronous methods that internally are using threads.

Comment: Right, that's true, but I'm suggesting that they don't do anything abnormal by generating their own threads (which node doesn't even provide you access to - just child processes)